# App created via the App Registration Portal is not visible in Azure Active Directory->App Registrations list

Tags: azure-active-directory

Using a Microsoft personal account (not work or school) I created a Web App via the App Registration portal. However the same app does not show up in the Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations section. Any specific reason for the same or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps registered with a personal Microsoft account are not associated with an Azure Active Directory. They are purely associated with your Microsoft account. If you want it visible there, you need to use an Azure AD account (work/school).

They mention it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-register-an-app

> This means that you can not register an application in your Azure AD tenant using a personal Microsoft account. If you explicitly wish to register an application in a particular tenant, sign in with an account originally created in that tenant.

The reason is that your MS account has no home tenant. AAD users always have one, but personal accounts do not.