# Azure DevOps application client secret expired. How to renew?

Tags: azure-devops

5 years ago I registered an application in Azure DevOps [here](https://aex.dev.azure.com/app/register).

The client secret that was generated back then has now expired and I can't figure out how to renew this.

I tried editing the application and click save, and it generates a new secret, but it still has the same old expiration date.

All the documentation I have found talk about updating the client secret in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade) but my application is not listed there.

Comment: Can you link some of the documents you have already gone through? Did you also try to look under “All Applications” instead of just “Owned Applications”?

Comment: Yeah, this doc explains how I set up the application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops

This doc talks about expired client secrets for AAD applications so I am not sure if it is usable for my situation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/invalid-client-secret

Comment: I found this StackOverflow question today which seems to explain why I cannot see my app in the list, but I am not sure if that means that I just don't have any way to renew the client secret. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765776/app-created-via-the-app-registration-portal-is-not-visible-in-azure-active-direc

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you find a solution?  After a lot of research, I came to the conclusion that these Azure DevOps applications are probably not AAD applications at all.

Comment: Ultimately I was able to have the client secret manually regenerated with a new 5-year term by submitting a support ticket with Azure DevOps.  Hopefully they will find a way to automate the process.

Comment: Did you deleted the old secret? It normally requires you to even though you have an updated one.

Comment: @Kelv.Gonzales - That's for AAD apps, which these are not.  For these ADO apps, there's only one field for the secret.  Deleting and recreating the app itself would have worked, but would also have invalidated all our existing users.  MS Support create a new client secret, replacing the old one, on the existing app.  IMHO this should be baked in functionality, not requiring a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of this post is correct, there is no way to renew the client secret. However, you can register a new application, and migrate your existing one over and create a new secret that will last for another 5 years. Once the 5 years expire, repeat the process.

I hope this answer helps you solve your problem.

Comment: The problem with migrating to a new app is that all users were registered under the old one.  All of them will have to re-register.  It's not clear if the old user id and the new one will be the same, or matchable in any way.